# lightdm doesn't start

Tags: lightdm, gdm

Today when I started Ubuntu, it didn't start `lightdm`, showing a black screen.
I changed to console Ctrl-Alt-F1 and tried to start `lightdm` manually

```
sudo start lightdm
```

It threw me to the graphic console (Ctrl-Alt-F7) and showed the same black screen.
Moreover, it looks like it starts, the console returned the number of process,

```
lightdm start/running, process 3616
```

However, after

```
sudo stop lightdm
```

I got

```
stop: unknown instance
```

Then I started `gdm`

```
sudo start gdm
```

and `gdm` started normal. So, the problem in `lightdm`.

To solve the problem I tried to purge `lightdm` and reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get purge lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
```

The both ways didn't help.

Now I use `gdm`, but wants to restore `lightdm` if it is possible.

Thank you all for you help!

PS: I didn't install recently any additional driver (and haven't NVidia card at all).

PPS: Some additional information

```
$ sudo start lightdm
lightdm start/running, process 2466
$ dmesg | grep lightdm
[   18.284992] init: lightdm main process (1446) killed by TERM signal
[   57.691273] init: lightdm main process (2466) terminated with status 1

$ sudo start lightdm
lightdm start/running, process 8140
$ sudo cat /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log 
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting Light Display Manager 1.2.3, UID=0 PID=8140
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Loading configuration from /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xlocal
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Registered seat module xremote
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Adding default seat
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting seat
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting new display for automatic login as user stas
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Starting local X display
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+0.00s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Launching X Server
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Launching process 8145: /usr/bin/X :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Acquired bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
[+0.01s] DEBUG: Registering seat with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Process 8145 exited with return value 1
[+0.03s] DEBUG: X server stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Display server stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Stopping display
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Display stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Stopping X local seat, failed to start a display
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Stopping seat
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Seat stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Required seat has stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Stopping display manager
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Display manager stopped
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Stopping daemon
[+0.03s] DEBUG: Exiting with return value 1

$ sudo cat x-0.log
X: cannot stat /etc/X11/X (No such file or directory), aborting.
```

Comment: Can you check the lightdm log in `/var/log/lightdm`?

Comment: Thank you. I've added the output of `cat /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`.

Comment: Try looking at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` to see why X is quitting.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it looks like nothng added to `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. I've done the following commands 
`sudo cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log > 1.log`

`sudo start lightdm` 

`sudo cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log > 2.log` 

The files `1.log` and `2.log` are identical. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> then:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop (for Gnome)

sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop (for Unity)

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

if you wish to backup `X` so not to worry:

```
sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
```

after all of this start `X` display:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/gdm start (for Gnome)

sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm start (for Unity)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! `lightdm` starts as normal.

Comment: you're welcome, good luck!

Comment: dpkg-query: package "xserver-org" is not installed and no information is available

Comment: it's *xserver-xorg* package not *xserver-org* and what is your comment about exactly? what are you trying to do and what is your distro version?

Comment: dpkg-query: package "xserver-xorg" is not installed.

Comment: I was getting `Unknown instance` with `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm stop`, so I did `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart`, which worked