# Lightdm does not start automatically

Tags: lubuntu, lightdm, gui, lxde

When booting Lubuntu 14.04, a terminal screen is shown instead of the usual graphical log-in screen. Then, I have to type sudo lightdm and use Ctrl+Alt+F7 to switch to the graphical log-in screen.

I checked `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager` as described on https://askubuntu.com/a/84485/288322; this included `/usr/sbin/lightdm` already. 
I also did as described on https://askubuntu.com/a/457694; that works fine.

How can I repair the system so that it automatically boots the graphical log-in screen again?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in terminal:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

This opens Grub boot loader config file with text editor.

Do below changes:

Uncomment the line `#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`, by removing # at the beginning, which will enable the Ubuntu purple screen.

Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="text"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`, this makes Ubuntu boot  into Graphical Mode.

Comment this line `#GRUB_TERMINAL=console`, by adding the # to the beginning.

After saved the changes, update grub via command:

`sudo update-grub`

Restart your computer and see the result.

[Reference](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/01/boot-into-text-console-ubuntu-linux-14-04/)

Comment: The file was already looking as you described. I ran `sudo update-grub` anyways, restarted the computer, but the problem continues to exist.

Comment: I thought it might... Different problem. Try `sudo apt-get install fglrx`, then `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: After doing that, the problem continues to exist. Now, I also did as described in http://askubuntu.com/a/195916 for my graphic card GeForce 9300 GE, but that also did not help. For some reason, it is not any longer possible to log in on the log-in screen after 'sudo lightdm' and Ctrl+Alt+F7; here I get the message `Error reading existing Xauthority: Failed to open file '/home/username/.Xauthority': Permission denied`. Finally, I tried `sudo update-grub`, but it did not improve. Shall I re-install Lubuntu 14.04?

Comment: I re-installed Lubuntu 14.04; works fine. Thanks!