# Stuck in a login loop Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: 14.04, unity, login

So this is what happened. I tried to power off my laptop using the classical power off button in Unity. My laptop went through the normal power off procedure, but suddenly, Ubuntu got stuck on a black screen with a white dash. Typical black screen.

I issued a REISUO sequence to power off my computer, since it's the safest way that I know of to power off a hanged computer. So the computer powered off.

Some time later, I went to power on Ubuntu, but something strange happened. First, Ubuntu took way less than expected to boot, maybe 5 to 10 seconds less. Then, when trying to log in to the computer, I was stuck in a boot loop.

I did the proper `cat .xsession-errors` and this is the output.

```
Script for ibus started at run_im.
Script for auto started at run_im.
Script for default started at run_im.
init: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2429) terminated with status 1
init: unity-settings-daemon main process (2422) killed by TERM signal
init: logrotate main process (2340) killed by TERM signal
init: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_lib_unity_unity-panel-service.1000.crash) main process (2410) killed by TERM signal
init: xsession-init main process (2419) killed by TERM signal
init: hud main process (2426) killed by TERM signal
init: unity-panel-service main process (2435) killed by TERM signal
init: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
init: job window-stack-bridge failed to stop
```

Any help would be very much apreciated, since this problem has been bugging me for a couple of weeks now, and I've done a lot of research but to date haven't got back into my desktop.

I did:

- `chown .Xauthority username:username` **NO FIX**

Thanks in advanced for any help you guys can give me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a TERM signal is ending the process that is required to login to your account. I'm not sure how to fix it, but I did a little searching around and found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596907/login-loop-unable-to-run-unity-not-xauthority-ownership-but-may-be-related-t), I think it may be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Giving it a try.