# Ubuntu 18.04 - Unity Quit Working

Tags: unity, 18.04

I am using Unity with Ubuntu 18.04. When I try to login, Unity crashes and automatically logs out. I never see my desktop environment anymore. I am forced to use something else. How do I begin to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Do you mean you are having a login loop? If yes, check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/596907/login-loop-unable-to-run-unity-not-xauthority-ownership-but-may-be-related-t

Comment: I will try but I don't think it is a login loop. I can see the desktop background for several seconds and then I am logged out.