# How can I start lightdm / server X?

Tags: server, lightdm

I installed yesterday new drivers from NVIDIA in my Ubuntu 14.04. I had to stop server X so I used the "famous"

`sudo service lightdm stop`

Today I updated my system and it seems like lightdm is off. I tried to start again the process with:

`sudo service lightdm start`

Nothing happened. The result was:

`start: service failed to start`

If I try to restart it also fails, and if I try to stop it again (to reinstall the drivers, because I don't know what else I can do) this happens:

`stop: Unknown instance:`

What can I do?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/455983/lightdm-doesnt-start

Comment: When I try

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
dpkg-query: package 'xserver-xorg' is not installed and no information is available`

I don't know why it's happening. I have two computers, and happened exactly the same in both. One works, the other one no...

Comment: Why don't you try reinstalling it along with its config files and then never stopping it again?

Comment: Because I have two screens and without installing NVIDIA drivers (which needs to stop X server) they don't work.